# Calling ExifInterface in a loop causing java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, image-processing, stack-overflow

I'm working on something that needs to call ExifInterface for all camera images to get images location and time, It's working fine for most of the devices but it causing java.lang.StackOverflowError in some devices like **Redmi 3S**.

What I'm doing is something like this.

```
for (String imagePath : paths) {
      ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
      float[] latlng = new float[2];
      if(exif.getLatLong(latlng)){
        //====rest of the process happened here.
      }
 }
```

this is stacktrace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
       at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:742)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:1940)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2041)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory(ExifInterface.java:2014)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.readExifSegment(ExifInterface.java:1863)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.getJpegAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1662)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1339)
       at android.media.ExifInterface.(ExifInterface.java)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any idea how can I stop this?

Comment: Read https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/

Comment: provide a stacktrace

Comment: @VladMatvienko Updated

Comment: Probably the issue is that for each item in your list, you are instancing a new Object. Of course, from the code above, we cannot see what are you doing in ExitInterface, but since initiating it, something must be also done there. Which means that on some weaker mobile phones it might get too much recursive operation which they cannot handle - in other words, you have to optimize your App with better architecture.

Comment: @DavidK Would it help if I create the object in constructor and initialise it here with image path, if you have anything better in your mind please tell me .

Comment: But what is exactly that you are doing inside ExitInterface once you pass it the image path? If you are manipulating images (downloading / uploading / resizing,..) I am sure this is the issue, as you are also doing it in list and hopefully in async task.

Comment: @DavidK Inside this method, I'm just adding those image in a List with their properties, the rest of processing happening somewhere else. And yes rest of processing happing in IntentService class.

Comment: But you already have a list of Paths, why are you copying it to another list? Shouldnt you just pass the existing List of Images to the ExitInterface? I think in ExitInterface you are trying to display the images from their path URL?

Comment: @DavidK In Paths list I've only have images path not their location or capture time, and yes I need to display the images as well latter once all the processing completed.

Comment: Have you tried replace the constructor to accept ListArray of Strings instead of each String?  In that case, you call only once ExitInterface and pass the entire List of ImagePaths which you are now iterating (in above code).

Then you move your code logic to ExitInterface entirely, you do not iterate anymore in the same class as you do now in above example. Create a method in ExitInterface which will do the same logic as you do now, but inside ExitInterface. And in your current class, instead of foreach call that method.

Comment: I had this issue too, but after I removed the exif.hasThumbnail() and exif.getThumbnailBitmap() code I have not had this issue again (only tested on emulator). I don't know if you have these methods in your //====rest of the process happened here.

Comment: I am also skipping images larger than 20 MB. Maybe that helps for you.

Comment: @Ankit Have you ever solved this problem? I'm facing the same issue now ,hope your experience can provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

Our app have also faced this problem, by following code:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getAbsolutePath());
int exifRotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
```

facebook project "fresco" also face the same issue, https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1661

I think this error is device specific and image specific, image need be large to reproduce this, and happening in Android's ExifInterface itself, we cannot do much here, maybe android sdk will fix this issue someday.

I suggest only use workaround solution to overcome this issue,

```
public static ExifInterface get(String path) throws IOException {
    try {
        return new ExifInterface(path);
    } catch (RuntimeException | StackOverflowError ex) {
        // Internal error in Android's EXIF API.
        Log.w(FX.LOG_TAG, "Android failed to perform EXIF analysis on image: " + path + ";\n" +  ex);
        throw new IOException(ex);
   }
}
```